# Taking a basis from an old basis in Free Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-abelian-group

> Let $G$ be a free abelian group with free generators $x_1,x_2,x_3$. We
>   want to show that $\forall g:=(g_{ij})\in \mathrm{GL_3}(\mathbb{Z})$,
>   the elements $u_j=\sum_{i=1}^{3} g_{ij}x_i,\ j=1,2,3$ are also free
>   generators of $G$.

My first thought is to show that the elements $u_j$ are $\mathbb{Z}-$linearly  independent and generating $G$. But this is not helpful, and I have definitely stuck.

Any ideas please?

*Thank you.*

Comment: Why do you think it is not helpful?

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier Thank you for your comment. I thought to connect the determinant of g with the linear independence, but I stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=g^{-1}$ be the inverse of $g$ in the linear group. Then we have a corresponding relation describing each $x_i$ in terms of $u_1,u_2,u_3$. (In the post, the sum is over $i$.)

From this, $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are also generators.
One can formally write:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
g_{11}&g_{12}&g_{13}\\
g_{21}&g_{22}&g_{23}\\
g_{31}&g_{32}&g_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{:=g}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11}&h_{12}&h_{13}\\
h_{21}&h_{22}&h_{23}\\
h_{31}&h_{32}&h_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{:=h}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
If $v$ is an elements, 
then it is generated by the $x$ basis, formally written, we find "$a$-scalars" such that
$$
v = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix}}_{a}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Then 
$$v = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
h_{11}&h_{12}&h_{13}\\
h_{21}&h_{22}&h_{23}\\
h_{31}&h_{32}&h_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{:=b}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
so $v$ is also generated by the $u$-system, use the components of $b$ above.

Let us now assume that we have a linear combination of the $u$-system, which is zero:
$$
0 = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix}}_{a}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\u_3
\end{bmatrix}\ .
$$
Then 
$$0 = 
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
g_{11}&g_{12}&g_{13}\\
g_{21}&g_{22}&g_{23}\\
g_{31}&g_{32}&g_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
}_{:=b}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}\ ,
$$
so $b=0$, since $x$ is a basis, so $a =agh=bh=0h=0$. This shows that the system $u$ is independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the hypothesis. Now it's clear!